# How to write the results of the codedui tests into csv file using c#?

Tags: c#, csv, coded-ui-tests, export-to-csv

I am executing the data driven tests by referring the data provided in a file named as 'data.csv'. The requirement is such that after execution of the testmethods, it should show the execution results(i.e. pass/fail) for each testmethod (or each row from this input file) in this same file i.e. 'data.csv' by updating the results in this file.

Answer (score 0):

The below program will add a new column(named as 'Result') to the output file.

```
/*
* OLD data:
* Column1,Column2,Column3
* A,B,C
*/

//total number of records should be same 
List<string> newColumnData = new List<string>() { "Pass" }; // This list //can be the output for all the iterations that you have stored in a list
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("C://test.csv").ToList();
//add new column to the header row
lines[0] += ",Column 4";
int index = 1;
//add new column value for each row.
lines.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(line =>
{
    //-1 for header
    lines[index] += "," + newColumnData[index - 1];
    index++;
});
//write the new content
File.WriteAllLines("C://test.csv", lines);

/*
* NEW data:
* Column1,Column2,Column3,Result
* A,B,C, Pass
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the directories provided from `TestContext` to write your file to.

```
TestContext.TestRunResultsDirectory
TestContext.TestResultsDirectory
TestContext.TestRunDirectory
```

But if your trying to generate data/statistics for your test runs I would recommend using [MTM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff472576.aspx) and its associated automation testing system, It will track every test ever ran and produce reporting (pie charts, e.g.) of that status.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public controlTypeEntered wpf_Control<controlTypeEntered>(List<wpfControls_PropertyTypes> propertyType, List<String> propertyValue, WpfControl controlWindow) where controlTypeEntered : WpfControl

    {
        controlTypeEntered wpfElement = (controlTypeEntered)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(controlTypeEntered), new object[] { controlWindow });
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        for (var i = 0; i < propertyType.Count; i++)
        {
            ht.Add(propertyType[i], propertyValue[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < propertyType.Count; i++)
        {
            // Identifying the control on basis of its search properties.
            if (propertyType[i] == wpfControls_PropertyTypes.ClassName)
            {
                wpfElement.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = propertyValue[i];
            }
            else if (propertyType[i] == wpfControls_PropertyTypes.ControlType)
            {
                wpfElement.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = propertyValue[i];
            }
            else if (propertyType[i] == wpfControls_PropertyTypes.FriendlyName)
            {
                wpfElement.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.FriendlyName] = propertyValue[i];
            }
            else if (propertyType[i] == wpfControls_PropertyTypes.Name)
            {
                wpfElement.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.Name] = propertyValue[i];
            }
            else if (propertyType[i] == wpfControls_PropertyTypes.TechnologyName)
            {
                wpfElement.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.TechnologyName] = propertyValue[i];
            }
        }
        return (controlTypeEntered)Convert.ChangeType(wpfElement, typeof(controlTypeEntered));
    }
```